# Flick a UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

When a user makes a flick gesture on a UIScrollView, the UIScrollView gets a momentum and starts moving, then slow down and finally stop. 
But how can I make this happen programmatically? I mean without a finger flicking, the UIScrollView just start moving automatically and then slow down to a speed of 0.

In my app I have made my UIScrollView unlike a normal UIScrollView (say it looks like a roller), so I want make a hint to the user that he can scroll it (and then everything get started!)

I have googled a lot but there seemed no way to solve my problem. The setContentOffset just couldn't make the natural "slow down and stop at somewhere ahead" effect.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, i don't understand, you want to create custom scroll animation to UIscrollView?

Comment: No, I don't want to create custom scroll animation to UIScrollView, but want the UIScrollView to scroll automatically like it was flicked by your finger. Say it's like first the scroll view is static there, then it suddenly starts moving, like someone has made a flick gesture on it but no one did that, then it naturally slows down and finally stop at somewhere.

Comment: try my code, may be it is helped to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, something like this >

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:.8];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:(abs(1-3)*0.3)];
self.myScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 500);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It is not currently what you need, but you can customise this code, and may be all be ok)

---

or use this code>

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.
                      delay:0.3
     usingSpringWithDamping:1.
      initialSpringVelocity:7.
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                        //Animations
                        self.myScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 500);
                    }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //Completion Block
                 }];
```

I think it is like you want(animation with damping like swipe effect)

Comment: It works for me! Thank you so much for this great sharing! ;)